# Question about transition matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear map defined as
$$T(x,y,z)=(-2x+y+z,y+2z,2x+z).$$
The matrix $A$ associated to $T$ with respect to the canonical basis is therefore
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 2\\
2 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
I want to compute the matrix associated to $T$ with respect to the basis $B=\{(2,1,0),(1,1,0),(0,1,1)\}$.

Therefore I've computed the images $T(2,1,0)=(-3,1,4), T(1,1,0)=(-1,1,2), T(0,1,1)=(2,3,1)$.

Thus I need to find scalars $a,b,c$ (different for the 3 systems, but for sake of notation I use the same letters) such that

$$(-3,1,4)=a(2,1,0)+b(1,1,0)+c(0,1,1)\implies (a,b,c)=(0,-3,4)$$
$$(-1,1,2)=a(2,1,0)+b(1,1,0)+c(0,1,1)\implies (a,b,c)=(0,-1,2)$$
$$(2,3,1)=a(2,1,0)+b(1,1,0)+c(0,1,1)\implies (a,b,c)=(0,2,1)$$

The associated matrix therefore should be

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
-3 & -1 & 2\\
4 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

and this looks a bit suspicious (ok, it's  not wrong in principle to have a row equal to 0 for a linear map, but I picked this basis quite randomly): also, I don't see why we should end up like this.

Moreover, if I compute the matrix as $M_B^B=M_B^CM_C^CM_B^C$, where $C$ is the canonical basis, I otbain:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-7 & 10 & -6 \\
-2 & 4 & 0 \\
2 & -2 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

where $M_B^C$ is equal to

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I apologize in advance for the question: I know this forum isn't meant to solve homeworks (and I swear this isn't, I'm a master student in mathematics and I was trying to see how much I remember of linear algebra), but here I don't know if there's some logical mistake I'm doing (the computations look fine, I've repeated them 2 times). Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first matrix is correct. Your second approach is theoretically correct, but it seems to me that what you have actually computed was$$M_B^C\begin{bmatrix}-2&1&1\\0&1&2\\2&0&1\end{bmatrix}M_C^B,$$since this is equal to the matrix that you got.

Comment: Dear @josècarlossantos, thanks a lot for the fast reply! I see, I should have computed $M_B^B=M^B_CM_C^CM^C_B$: I I got confused with the composition. Thanks again and have a nice day!